# Facebook API - How can I store multiple access tokens without the user to need to log in again?

Tags: php, facebook

For my application, I need to be able to get some datas from 0-x FB accounts for each person.

I have the authentication process working, I get the different access tokens, but they become invalid very quickly because, when the user logs in as a different account, the token from the previous one becomes invalid.

Problem is, I need to get the datas I want all at the same time, so I can't ask them to login with their multiple accounts each time they come on the website...

If anyone has an idea...

Thanks for your help =)

Comment: Since users can only have one Facebook account it's unlikely this is supported in any meaningful way, but surely the long-lived tokens from the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) documentation aren't expiring just because the user logged out of Facebook?

Comment: As far as I understood the documentation I already have a long-lived token, my authentication process being the server-side one.
My app will be for business, and for big companies, I wonder if it's not possible that they have multiple FB accounts.
Hootsuite seems to permit that btw :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase 2 table columns in your app namely short_access_token & long_access_token for each user.

Once user authenticates your app, an access token is generated, store it in short_access_token. Then pass this access token to:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
client_id=APP_ID& client_secret=APP_SECRET& grant_type=fb_exchange_token& fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN

Once you run this, an access token with 60 days validity will be generated. Store it in long_access_token. Now, use this long_access_token for 60 days.

You can generate long lived access token only once a day i.e. the first time. Use this long lived access token for your tasks (if you've already got the permission).

Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Yeah, tried the exchange token yesterday and this morning, but the problem is still there.

When I use only one account, the token works for some time (many days/weeks), but when I try to store tokens for more than 1 account, the other accounts' tokens are invalidated.

Comment: Are you storing long lived access token for each user? You need to pass different short access token of every user to get a new long lived access token.